# How to test my google script URL as deploy web app for two data?

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to discuss with anyone here regarding my problem.
My problem is that, I cannot successfully test my code.gs in google script with two data when I deploy it as web app. When I test it only one data it say *'Ok'*, but when I try to test adding a second data it say *'unsupported parameter'*.

When I deploy the script as web app, the link is as below:

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyXlCLBDNzJGXWNkrEHtWP0jaxnpvX0dPUnXjwilioUd7up-SU/exec
```

how can I test it?
Is it like,

[1]

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyXlCLBDNzJGXWNkrEHtWP0jaxnpvX0dPUnXjwilioUd7up-SU/exec?**BBTTempData=32.56&RTtempData=25.6**

or

[2]
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyXlCLBDNzJGXWNkrEHtWP0jaxnpvX0dPUnXjwilioUd7up-SU/exec?**BBTTempData=32.56/RTtempData=25.6**

My code is just like below:

```
function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log( JSON.stringify(e) );  // view parameters
  var result = 'Ok'; // assume success
  if (e.parameter == undefined) {
    result = 'No Parameters';
  }
  else {
    var id = '<mygooglespreadsheet_id>'; //docs.google.com/spreadsheetURL/d
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getActiveSheet();
    var newRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
    var rowData = [];
    rowData[0] = new Date(); // Timestamp in column A

    for (var param in e.parameter) {
      Logger.log('In for loop, param='+param);
      var value = stripQuotes(e.parameter[param]);
      //Logger.log(param + ':' + e.parameter[param]);
      switch (param) {
        case 'BBTTempData': //Parameter
          rowData[1] = value; //Value in column B
          break;
        case 'RTtempData':
          rowData[2] = value;
          break;
        default:
          result = "unsupported parameter";
      }
    }
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(rowData));
    // Write new row below
    var newRange = sheet.getRange(newRow, 1, 1, rowData.length);
    newRange.setValues([rowData]);
  }
  // Return result of operation
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result);
}

function stripQuotes( value ) {
  return value.replace(/^["']|['"]$/g, "");
}
```

The code, I get it in YouTube `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tWTv4-QUQ0E`.

A discussion is good for me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using 2 parameters you should use `BBTTempData=32.56&RTtempData=25.6` I've tested this and it works fine for me. Perhaps you need to re-deploy the web app to get it to work if you've been making changes to the code.

Comment: "Perhaps you need to re-deploy the web app to get it to work if you've been making changes to the code."


It's working..! ^^

Thank you James Donnellan.